# Any PHP or Python alternatives for Liferay and Alfresco?

Tags: java, php, python, liferay, alfresco

My company wants to use Liferay for developing a portal and integrate Alfresco with it for document management.
But both Liferay and Alfresco are Java based and i would like to know if there are any alternatives to Liferay and Alfresco in  PHP or Python.

Thank You

Comment: You may get more answers if you provide a quick summary of what Liferay and Alfresco actually do, for those of us motivated enough to try and help but too lazy to Google to find out what you're talking about. :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply Kylotan.Liferay is used for making portals which are web pages composed of portlets (something like iGoogle,where u add widgets to the page). Alfresco on the other hand,is used for creating a document repository and managing document workflow . Hope that makes it a little more clear :)

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you can have a look at [KnowledgeTree](http://www.knowledgetree.org/Platform_Requirements) as a substitution of Alfresco. It's mainly written in PHP.

Comment: Thanks aeby. KnowledgeTree looks good :).Any corresponding PHP based portal development framework which i use in conjunction with KnowledgeTree ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems both are content management systems. Here you'll find a couple of [proprietary PHP based CMS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP). As for opensource solutions, there are many.

- PHP

  - [Joomla](http://www.joomla.org/)
  - [Drupal](http://drupal.org/)
  - [And many more](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#PHP_2)
- Python

  - [Django-CMS](http://django-cms.org/)
  - [And others..](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_content_management_systems#Python)

I don't know how *enterprisy* these are (nor do I have much experience with them), but Joomla and Drupal are quite popular. Django is great, so I would expect a django based CMS to be good.